# Does anybody has ever constructed QC-LDPC Codes using finite geometries?

Tags: information-theory

I'm a newcomer to this field, and by reading channel code:morern and classical, I still can not get the key point, so maybe someone has done this work before and can give some advices or perhaps some codes?

Comment: Asking Google with keywords "finite geometry coding", I obtained at once many documents in particular this one entitled "Applications of finite geometry in coding theory and cryptography by A. KLEIN, L. STORME

Comment: @ Jean Marie, great thanks for you, sir.

Comment: Do somebody has matlab code for design theses codes?

Comment: See this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5952.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the helpful comment by @JeanMarie since you are relatively new I am giving some pointers.

Here is another reference:

A decoding algorithm for finite geometry LDPC codes by Liu and Pados,
*IEEE Transactions on Communications*,53(3), 2005.

This paper can easily be found online. As for request for matlab code, this is not normally on scope for this forum. However, I do know that

1. Magma which is a mathematical programming language focused on discrete mathematics (with a calculator available online) has the facility to encode/decode LDPC codes. See [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1930#21839)
2. Googling "matlab LDPC encoder" yields a lot of results.

Happy hunting.

Comment: Great thanks for you, sir!